# image source in not dynamic action in html

Tags: javascript, html

HTML view source code is:

```
<IMG style="DISPLAY: inline" src="https://admit.belgacom.be/WCE/ESW/img/load.gif" />
```

but When i login and reach this location, path is showing different as: (ESW is missing)

```
<IMG style="DISPLAY: inline" src="https://admit.belgacom.be/WCE/img/load.gif" />
```

Due to change of path, ie without ESW image is not getting loaded.

Note: I have javascript code in JSP where it replaces the new image due to IE settimeout issue as:

```
document.getElementById('imageId').src = \"../../img/load.gif\");
```

CODE:

```
<div id="toHide" class="pb-text-align-center">
    <img style="display: inline" id='imageId' src="img/load.gif" />
    <form wicket:id="safeForm" class="clearfix">
        <input type="hidden" wicket:id="submitted" value="false" />
    </form>
</div>  

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript"> 
    function setSubmit(){
    document.getElementById("safeForm4c").submit();  
    document.getElementById('imageId').src = "../../img/load.gif"; }
    if (document.getElementById("safeForm4c").submitted.value == "false") {
        document.getElementById("safeForm4c").submitted.value = "true";
        setTimeout('setSubmit()', 100); 
    }else{ document.getElementById("toHide").style.display="none";}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: And the question is? And why do you escape those string delimiters? It looks more like your server side code is wrong.

Comment: I don't understand: first you say that the "view source" code is one thing, but then you say it's different when you actually get to the page. What is the server-side environment?  Is it php? ASP? JSP?

Comment: there are 2 ways of entering application, one is as guest user, next is with login details. when i login, path gets changed. I am using java/JSP.

Comment: @kasim is your script in the same document as the HTML? If so I am revising my answer now

Comment: script, css, java, html files are in same location/directory.

Comment: No, no, no, we need to see your *server side* code, that's where the problem resides. You're merely providing an ugly hack to work around a bug. And remember: Java ≠ JavaScript.

Comment: @Marcel Kropel I agree, what struck me initially though is a common issue with relative file locations, if you look at the code we have 2 file locations - 1 in the HTML and another in the JavaScript, if both values are correct then files are in different locations on the server, not in the same location as previously stated - but kasim says has tried this so now moving forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by assigning dynamic image path instead of ../../img/load.gif as:

> //document.getElementById('imageId').src
>   = \"../../img/load.gif\");
>
> document.getElementById('imageId').src
>   = **document.getElementById('imageId').src;**

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript"> 
        function setSubmit(){
        document.getElementById("safeForm4c").submit();  
        document.getElementById('imageId').src = document.getElementById('imageId').src; }
        if (document.getElementById("safeForm4c").submitted.value == "false") {
            document.getElementById("safeForm4c").submitted.value = "true";
            setTimeout('setSubmit()', 100); 
        }else{ document.getElementById("toHide").style.display="none";}
    </SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possability is your file structure and relative locations, to give a complete answer on script issue or files structure we would need to see what you have in place.

Assuming that it isn't scripting, from your post it looks like the JavaScript is in a folder at the same level as img, for example, looking at the file structure I believe this is where your files are stored

/htdocs/WCE/ESW/img/load.gif is the path to your image

/htdocs/WCE/alt1/alt2/java.js is the path the src property is being referenced from

Now when i put in the ../../img/load.gif this will go back to /htdocs/WCE/img/load.gif cutting out the ESW folder.

If this is the case you will need to look at your file structures to work out the correct path (probably ../img/load.gif), if you have trouble post them here and I (or another here) can try to help you work the path out.

I hope this helps.

UPDATED AS A RESULT OF CODE ADDITION:

If your script is in the same page as your HTML try removing ../../ from your JavaScript

Comment: when i remove ../, image is not getting relaoded through javascript. initially gets loaded, but reloading deosnt happen.

Comment: @kasim can you please share more code that handles the initial load and the re-load?